# AWS Cognito User Pools iOS Explicit Sign In vs. Delegate

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In the AWS documentation for User Pool Sign in it says that there are two ways to sign in: either explicitly or when credentials are needed via a delegate. I was wondering what this distinction is and what would be proper use cases for the two. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit flow is for cases when you already know the username and password. If you want to build an interactive login experience you should use the delegates.

A delegate will automatically prompt the user for their username and password once the refresh token expires by calling `getPasswordAuthenticationDetails`. Explicit flow will never do that, so it should only be used for cases which are either short lived our your app logic manages the logic to check refresh token validity and ask the user for their credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if you wanted to build a log in where the user only has to log in once and then stay logged in whenever they open the app would you use the delegate? and if so how would that be set up

Comment: Yes. Refer to [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/walkthrough-using-the-ios-sdk.html) for how to setup the iOS SDK.